# Negate an external script dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic landing page that loads its content based on a parameter, this landing page has external scripts.
Now I have a condition that if met, it will negate or not execute an external script. Is that possible?

The external script has a lot of function there that is running on load, but I don't need it if the condition is met.

Let's say:

```
var k = aa;
if(k == "aa") {
    // run something
} else {
    // negate an external script
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have change access to the external script, then **include the check into the script directly** and always execute it.

If not, **[jQuery's `getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) function** could be an option:

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```